# wrong exception handling in feed_dict in tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I create my tensorflow graph as following:

```
s = tf.zeros([T+1, self.hidden_dim])
o = tf.zeros([T, self.word_dim])
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
c = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
d = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
dot_product = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(a, b))
s_t = tf.nn.tanh(c + d)
o_t = dot_product
```

Then afterwards run it as following:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
     sess.run(s)
     sess.run(o)
     print type(self.W)
     # For each time step...
     for t in range(T):
          product = sess.run(dot_product, feed_dict={a: self.W, b: s[t-1]})
          s[t] = sess.run(s_t, feed_dict={c: self.U[:, x[t]], d: product}) 
          o[t] = sess.run(o_t, feed_dict={a: self.V, b: s[t]})
```

Fome reason, I get the following exception:

```
TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, or numpy ndarrays.
```

This eror occures on

```
product = sess.run(dot_product, feed_dict={a: self.W, b: s[t-1]})
```

But "W" is type of numpy.ndarray. Where is the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: What is `s` because that could be the Tensor object? In fact you're running s so that's probably a Tensor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TF complains because your variable `s` is a `tf.Tensor` (it has no problems with your 'W' variable).

It it would not be a tensor, this part of the code `sess.run(s)` would complain with something like this: `Fetch argument XX has invalid type <type 'YY'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a YY into a Tensor or Operation.)`